# Mongodb java springdata unable to get result for date equals query

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I have inserted some test records to the mongo database with following structure.

> {
>     "_id" : ObjectId("5563fe96a826638b48c77c26"),
>
> "date" : ISODate("2015-05-02T07:00:00.326Z"),
>
> "createdDate" : ISODate("2015-05-26T05:03:18.899Z"),
>
> "updatedDate" : ISODate("2015-05-26T05:03:18.899Z"),
>
> "status" : 0
>
> }

Now when I try to query it using Spring data or via MongoDB I am always getting returned result list size to be 0.

```
Calendar  calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(2015, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0);
Query query = new Query();      
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("date").is(calendar.getTime());
List<DateRecord> attendanceList = findAll(query, DateRecord.class);
System.out.println(attendanceList.size());
```

I am getting a very similar result for BasicDBObject, list of size 0.

```
DBCursor cursor;
BasicDBObject query1 = new BasicDBObject();
query1.append("date", calendar.getTime());

cursor = collection.find(query1);
System.out.println("Total objects returned "+cursor.size());
```

Any pointers on same will be highly appreciated. All I just want that data should be returned based upon year,month and day and any timestamp field values should be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a different query - look for date greater than 2015-4-2 00:00:00 and explicitly less than 2015-4-3:00:00:00

Another approach, that I'm less enthusiastic about, would be to to add a field to the document just for the search purpose (e.g. "dateWithoutHour" calculated by java just before saving a document, and assuming data doesn't arrive from other sources). I don't like it, because I prefer my data to be pure logic and not change any time someone comes up with a new search requirement... but sometimes I had to resort to it).

And as always, when facing a difficult query it's tempting to consider $where , but I won't recommend it because it can't use indices.

Comment: hmmm agreed it should work, but I was thinking that there must be an elegant way as well of doing this as this seems to be a very common requirement so just was thinking how others do this.

Comment: Yeah, I was also expecting it to be built-in. Unfortunately at the time we investigated it from another angle and got a strong impression it's missing (our angle was, we saw operations such as "$year", "$dayOfYear" in the *aggregate* framework, and were disappointed they're not available for 'find'). Admittedly I don't work for mongodb so I could be missing something, but it was a decent investigation.